# CreateJS Tween on keyDown

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

I ahave a problem implementing TweenJS on keydown. It only tweens once and after that if I press key there is no another tween.

What I have so far is:

```
var rotate =  false;

document.onkeydown = keyDown;
document.onkeyup = keyUp;

function keyDown(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 32:
            if(!rotate) {
                rotate = true;
                var t = createjs.Tween.get(rect).to({rotation:360},450, createjs.Ease.BackInOut).call(function(){
                        rotate = false;
                    });
                }
            break;
        }
    }
```

As I said, if I hit space, the rectangle rotates just as I want but after it finished rotation var rotate is set back to false as I wanted and after another press on space there is no another rotation.

So, my question is How to tween some element on click or keyDown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have already rotated the `rect` to 360, so rotating it again does nothing (it is already at its target).

An easy solution is to toss in a zero-duration `to()` call before or after the main rotation, which resets the rotation value so it can be tweened again.

```
createjs.Tween.get(rect)
    .to({rotation:0}) // THIS ONE
    .to({rotation:360}, 450, createjs.Ease.BackInOut)
    .call(function(){
        rotate = false;
        // You could also reset it here:
        // rect.rotation = 0;
    });
```